# Scraped data into a xlsx file

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I can bring my **scraping** data but only in the csv format, here is my code

```
def write_csv(ads):
    with open('results.csv','w',newline='', encoding = 'utf-8') as f:

        fields= ['Titulo','Preco']
        header=['Título,Preco']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fields)
       

        for ad in ads:
            writer.writerow(ad)
```

and bring me data like that

```
Produto;Preco
xxxxx;$$$$$
```

how to bring this data to xlsx?

| Titulo | Preco |
| --- | --- |
| First | row |
| Second | row |

Comment: FYI it's __scraping__ (and __scrape__, __scraped__, __scraper__) not scrapping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pandas to output the file in excel.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("results.csv", index_col=False)
df.to_excel("results.xlsx", index=False)
```